# How do I set setReverseLayout() in my code?

Tags: java, android

I wanted to create Reverse Order in my recyclerview.

```
     recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
     recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this).setReverseLayout(true));
```

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:reverseLayout="true"
            app:stackFromEnd="true"/>
```

But I got error that said  setLayoutManager cannot be applied (void)

this is what I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);// the last parameter (true) means Reverse be enable or not
 recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```